# Bad quality when overlaying PNG with FFMpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm trying to overlay a PNG over an animated GIF using FFMpeg.

The image is outputted correctly, but both the GIF and PNG are considerably lower quality. I've tried a few things, but can't figure it out.

I have:

```
ffmpeg
-i animated.gif
-i overlay.png
-filter_complex 'overlay=10:10, palettegen'
palette.png -y

ffmpeg
-i animated.gif
-i overlay.png
-i palette.png
-filter_complex 'overlay=10:10, paletteuse'
animated-overlay.gif -y
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `format` overlay option to avoid the default conversion to yuv420p in overlay filter.

```
overlay=10:10:format=auto
```

See the [overlay filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) for other accepted values.